# Can Hibernate use logical name for entity property different from field name?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Let's say, there's a Hibernate entity configured with field access by means of annotations. I would like to map a Java class field `_name` so that its logical name for Hibernate be `name`, for instance, when referred from HQL queries. I need this mostly for collections.

Anticipating improper suggestions: switching access type to "property" is not possible; the task has nothing to do with the name of the physical column.

Comment: If this helps, my grand intent is to marry Hibernate with Scala so that Java collections be used for mapping on the low level while appropriate Scala collection wrappers be exposed outside. Unfortunately, though JVM allows self-titled fields and methods, Scala can't support it so it seems not possible to create Java-style field with `name` and Scala accessor to it called `name()`

Comment: You could try a hibernate custom PropertyAccessor, but that seems to be broken: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HCANN-48 :(

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding of your question - 
You could define the entity like this. This will generate a hibernate table named (NewName_ABC with a column name)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NewName_ABC")
public class ABC
{
.
@Column(name = "name")
private string _name;
.
.
}
```

parallely can use liquibase to create the table.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
@Column(name = "name")
private string _name;
```

Comment: No. It's not about the column name. I want that an HQL like this one be possible: `select name from SomeEntity`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the second property with a different name points to the same column and use it in HQL queries. But there is a restriction: only one of those properties can be mapped as insertable, updatable.

```
@Column(name="name")
private string name;

@Column(name="name", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private string alsoName;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I mostly interested in aliasing of collections

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias in HQL as you use in SQL. You don't need to specify any annotation for that. Annotations can be added while queries:

SELECT id from name _name